# Python 3 KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, cucumber, python-behave

Im getting a KeyError: "'**name**' not in globals" when I import a page object model from a step python file.
Im using python 3.

features/steps/tutorial.feature

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from behave import *


from ..lib.pages.login_page import LoginPage

use_step_matcher("re")


@given("user is lead to the login page")
def step_impl(context):
    """
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    context.browser.get("https://www.phptravels.net/login")


@when("I log in")
def step_impl(context):
    """
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    page = LoginPage(context)
    page.login()
```

features/lib/pages/login_page.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec


class LoginPage:
    locator_dictionary = {
        "email_field": (By.NAME, 'username'),
        "password_field": (By.ID, 'password'),
        "login_button": (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.btn.btn-action.btn-lg.btn-block.loginbtn'),
        "accept_cookies": (By.ID, 'cookyGotItBtn')
    }

    def __init__(self, context):
        self.browser = context.browser

    def login(self, username="xxxxx", passwd="xxxxx"):
        b = self.browser

        WebDriverWait(b, 10).until(
            ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "cookyGotItBtn"))).click()

        b.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(username)
        b.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(passwd)
        b.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-action.btn-lg.btn-block.loginbtn').click()
```

features/tutorial.feature

```
Feature: showing off behave

  Background: user is lead to the login page
    Given user is lead to the login page

  Scenario: login invalid
    When I log in
```

My directory structure is:

```
E:features\tutorial.feature
E:features\__init__.py
E:features\lib\__init__.py
E:features\lib\pages\__init__.py
E:features\lib\pages\login_page.py
E:features\steps\__init__.py
E:features\steps\tutorial.py
```

File "steps/tutorial.py", line 8, in 
    from ..lib.pages.login_page import LoginPage
KeyError: "'**name**' not in globals"

Answer (score 0):

You most probably need to put package name in import path:

```py
from features.lib.pages.login_page import LoginPage
```

Comment: thanks for replying, although I tried that and I got the following: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'features'
I have no idea why

Comment: You need to add features to your path. I guess you're using windows, so i believe ``` import sys; sys.path.append("e:\\features") ``` or such would work for you

Comment: im using macbook

Comment: well, the e:\\ would not work for you, since you are using macbook. What i meant was to find the correct path to your working directory and add it to your sys.path. For example, if /home/xfx/features is your working directory, add /home/xfx to your sys.path and from features.lib... import ...

Comment: this is my path to the features directory: '/Users/fran/PycharmProjects/prueba1/features' and I added it to sys.path, I printed it and its there but still does not work, so frustrating.

Comment: now I added  '/Users/fran/PycharmProjects/prueba1' and it worked!! thank you very much man!!!

Comment: Is there another way to make it work? For example adding that path to any python configuration? So I don't need to put it in code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm you do not have relative imports?

As a mitigation you can try importing LoginPage just before its use.

```
@when("I log in")
    def step_impl(context):
    """
    :type context: behave.runner.Context
    """
    from ..lib.pages.login_page import LoginPage
    page = LoginPage(context)
    page.login()
```

Comment: Thats the only import I have. Now I put it before its use but I still get the KeyError: "'name' not in globals".

Comment: If I import it as '''from features.lib.pages.login_page import LoginPage''' l get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'features'